# In sourcetree how can I avoid messages "(cherry picked from xxx)"?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, cherry-pick

In the last version of sourcetree (3.1.3), when I cherry-pick commits, the new commit includes a comment `(cherry picked from xxx)`.  I don't want that message.

I read somewhere else it is the result of option `-x` in `git cherry-pick`.  So probably there was a change in how sourcetree translates user actions to git commands.  It adds option `-x`.

Is there any way to tell sourcetree to do the cherry-pick the old way, without option `-x`?  Or without changing the commit message?

Answer (score 0):

**Incomplete answer**

On the command line, depending on your git version, you might want to try the [`-r` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt--r) to cancel `-x`.

Now for sourcetree i'm unsure about how to make it use that setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the cherry pick from the GUI, it will show a checkbox 'Include commit IDs in the merge commit message'. Untick and it will work

Comment: Thanks.  I had to update to the last version to see it.  Is there a way to make it unchecked by default?